# I built an LF33CV circuit, but am getting no output

Tags: voltage-regulator

[LF33CV](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/lfxx-1849555.pdf) circuit:

[image: LF33CV circuit]

5 V is applied to pin 1, GND to pin 2. I still have no output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show a picture of the physical circuit.

Comment: You have 3V3 connected to I2C pin3

Comment: Try to draw your circuits with ground facing down, power facing up, and signals flowing left to right. It'll make things a lot easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw your schematic in a cleaner manner, with ground facing down and things flowing in a logical left-to-right manner, it becomes a lot easier to debug things:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9zI3I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The labels you've used are confusing. I would assume that "I2C_RPI" is an I2C line of some sort (is it SCL? SDA?) but LM33 is a voltage regulator product line, and not the one you're using here. It isn't clear what I2C_V means, either. I would assume that 3V3_PIN17 is where you intended to supply 3.3V to, so maybe that's where you've made a mistake?

The circuit itself looks fine in terms of construction, although with the LF33 has very specific requirements for the output capacitance. 10μF is the maximum output capacitance allowed, which means that if your load also has bulk decoupling capacitors you are exceeding the maximum output bypass capacitance (\$C_O\$) specification in the LF33 datasheet. The ESR range of the capacitor is also limited (0.1Ω to 10Ω), so with multiple capacitors in parallel you may end up violating that specification too.

I would honestly consider an alternative regulator here, such as LM1117-3.3 or any of its many clones (LD1117-3.3, AMS1117-3.3, etc.), which doesn't have the same limitations on output capacitance.

Comment: Sorry your drawing is exactly what I am doing. I figured out my issue. The diagram that came with the regulators was exactly backwards. It labeled the 5V in where it was the output 3.3V. I switched the input and output feed and it worked

Comment: Glad you figured it out in the end!

Comment: OK I have a confession. I thought I had this figured out but I do not. And I want to thank you for offering to help. This circuit is for a Raspberry Pi project I am working on. After doing some more testing I must have not read my meter correctly, it was late. So tonight I had some time and I am only getting .6v out with 5v in. Do I need some type of load on the output. If so how much. I also put the regulator in a bread board with just 5v and ground on it and only got .6v out. I added the .1uf on the input but that didn't help either. Maybe I got a bad batch of regulators.

Comment: You need both input and output capacitors on the LF33. I'd go with 100nF in, 4.7nF out, ensuring that the output cap is an electrolytic capacitor since the LF33 has specific ESR requirements that a ceramic capacitor 100% will not meet. I would certainly try applying at least 1mA of load (e.g. a resistor between 1kΩ and 3.3kΩ) before trying to measure it. But the LF33 is really not a great regulator, as I said in the post, and you'll probably find it far easier to just use one of the xx1117-3.3 regulators.

Comment: For the out capacitor do you mean a 4.7uf electrolytic. I used a 4.7uf and it was no help. This is so frustrating.  Also I have ordered the LM1117-3.3

Comment: Yes, 4.7uF electrolytic. I can't say I know for sure why your circuit is failing, if you're wiring it up correctly, but I wouldn't be surprised if you either got fake/broken LF33s. It's possible that they got fried by ESD due to improper storage (e.g. in regular bubble wrap or polythene bags). The xx1117-3.3 is probably the most-used 3.3V regulator on the planet, so if it doesn't work for you then you've got something wrong in your circuit.

Comment: OK I received  the XX1117 3.3 and they work great. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Steve Excellent! Don't forget to hit the accept button to the left of my answer :)